# Where should background job logic go

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, background-process, resque

I'm using Rails and Resque but this is more of a design question about where the actual logic should go with background jobs.

I have a class like this:

```
class Ticket
  # 1) should method go here?
end
```

and a BG job like this:

```
module Jobs
  class PayTicket
    # 2) or should the method go here?
  end
end
```

Then there's a method that handles the billing for Ticket. It makes two network calls (one of which will be slow), so it's clear we need a background job

```
  def pay_ticket
    # calls out to stripe and another network call
  end
```

1) If I put the logic in #1 above it seems to make sense to house that the logic to pay a ticket with the Ticket class. Then I would just instantiate the Ticket object in the BG job. The downside of this is that I don't want people to call the pay_ticket method outside of a background job, so then I need to add a comment that says "only call with BG job" etc... This seems like bad form.

2) If I put the pay_ticket logic in the BG job then I know it only gets called there, but then it's getting away from the class where it feels like it *should* go.

Would just like some general thoughts on if people have fat background jobs or if that logic typically stays in the models. Or if it depends on each situation. Thanks!

Comment: I know (or I think I know) what a `Ticket` is, but `PayTicket` doesn't sound like an object. Maybe your problem starts there.

Comment: @alexis It could be a TicketPaymentService. Does that sound like an object now?

Comment: Better. So what kind of things can a Service do? Can it pay tickets? Then the payment method belongs there, especially if you could imagine it being generalized, and it only relies on `Ticket`'s interface for the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you'd like to structure your code.  I'm a firm believer int the **fat** model design pattern, but it really is up to each developer.  Either way sounds as though it would be fine given the circumstances so I suppose my first question is, are you developing in shared project (ie. will other people be working on this code?)

If not, I'd say through it in the model and keep the logic related to the model as close to the source as possible.

If you are, it can be a little dangerous to expose that logic BUT a comment really isn't that big of a deal.

If you **REALLY** don't want anyone calling that method but want to follow an OOP/encapsulated approach you could always subclass the Ticket model so you have all of the functionality but don't expose the `pay` method.  For example:

```
# models/ticket.rb
class Ticket
    ...
end

# lib/payable_ticket.rb
class PayableTicket < Ticket
    def pay
        ....
    end
end
```

Just my two cents, but I hope that helps.

Comment: There are other ways to model this. For example a new object that only knows how to pay tickets. `TicketPayment.new(ticket).pay!` It doesnt need to be a ticket and it dosnt need to be a worker.